# Selecting a single photo album in android and get its content

Tags: android, photos

I'm working on my first app and all I want is to import/use/access all photos in a single album. In general the user should create a folder where my app can get custom artwork from.

So far I've build a ListView Dialog and have been at filling it with a list of folders in the gallery folder.

Then I found this: Selecting a single photo and getting it's album's contents.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041293/1931743

In a perfect world I'd use android's build in image picker to select a single album but I haven't found a solution for this.

What's your recommendation? Staying with ListView or is there a way of selecting a single album with stock Dialogs?

Thank You!

Comment: There is a `Gallery` View. or alternatives like coverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281129/android-gallery-view

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Comment: I think you're getting me wrong. I'm sorry.

What I want is a list of all pictures in one single album. I'm looking for the best way to select it (the album).